# How can change Swift 3 to 4 in Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, migration, xcode10.1, xcode11.4

Current I am using Xcode11.4. I need to use Xcode 11.4 for iOS 13 frameworks but I cant build my old project in Xcode 11 Here is the error message

```
This workplace has projects that contain source code developed with Swift 3.x.This version of Xcode does not support building or migrating Swift 3.x targets
Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4
```

I tried to change Swift Language version to Swift 4 in all Pods .
[image]

But Some of the Pods is showing error like that

[image: Error]

How Can I fixed that error,Does I need to install Xcode 10.1 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do the migration

1. Use Xcode 10.1's migration tool to update your code-base directly to swift4 
   But this will still require manual pod update
2. If your code-base is small, you can skip the hassle of downloading and installing of Xcode and could manually update code to swift 4 by refactoring.

Follow [this](https://medium.com/@timefrancesco/swift-4-migration-and-cocoapods-31e5ac020980) tutorial, It is comprehensive enough for migration

Comment: Thanks You ,I am solved with Xcode 10.1's migration tool

Answer (score 1):

In both `Project` and `Target` files -> "Build Settings" tab -> Swift Compiler Language ->Swift Language Version -> changing the Swift version from 4.0 to "Swift 5.0" worked for me